# unable to execute integration test for DB seeder - Error : Call to a member function connection() on null

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I am trying to write an integration test for my db seeder, but it does not seem to be returning an instance of that seeder. so it fails to execute

when i debug it the $adminUserSeeder is showing the following

[image]

this is my test

```
 namespace Tests\Unit\user;
use AdminUserSeeder;
use App\Test;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class AdminSeederTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testRun()
    {
        $adminUserSeeder = new AdminUserSeeder();
        $adminUserSeeder->run();
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', ['name' =>  'admin']);
    }

}
```

and this is my seeder class

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

```
class AdminUserSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
     $user = (new App\User)->where('name','admin')->first();
      if($user)
         {
             $user->delete();
         }
        factory(App\User::class,'admin')->create();
    }
}
```

added the stack trace

```
 /laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1138
/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1104
/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:936
/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:880
/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:843
/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1477
/database/seeds/AdminUserSeeder.php:10
/tests/Unit/AdminSeederTest.php:21
```

Comment: What's the stack of this exception?

Comment: added to the bottom of the post

Comment: Mabye AdminUserSeeder needs magic something so that it actually exists and new w/o further things is not enough to run()